# Help with optimising calls to the usort function in PHP

Tags: php, kohana, usort

This is my callback for my `usort()`

```
public function sortProperties($a, $b) {

        $sortA = inflector::camelize(str_replace('-', '_', $this->sortBy));
        $sortB = inflector::camelize(str_replace('-', '_', $this->sortBy));

        $a = Arr::get($a, $sortA);
        $b = Arr::get($b, $sortB);


        if (is_numeric($a) AND is_numeric($b)) {
            return  $a < $b; 
        } else {
            return strcasecmp($a, $b); 
        }


    }
```

Usually, when I see the first 2 lines in *any* of my code, it screams to me: *refactor!* I guess it's because they are identical.

I know I could make a function `getCamelized()`, but I don't think I'd use it again outside of this.

Is there a way to turn those 4 lines into 2? Could `func_get_args()` or `array_walk()` help me here?

Also, is there anything wrong about this sorting function?

Comment: Schwartzian Transform http://t3.dotgnu.info/blog/php/schwartzian-transform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to turn those 4 lines
>   into 2?

```
    $sortA = $sortB = inflector::camelize(str_replace('-', '_', $this->sortBy));
```

And for other two lines:

```
    list($a, $b) = array(Arr::get($a, $sortA), Arr::get($b, $sortB));
```

As for sort, it seems to be fine at least to me.

Comment: how is $sortA = $sortB and $a = $b going to help?

Comment: `$a = $b = Arr::get($a, $sortA);` Won't this set $a and $b to what $a will be?

Comment: @Ben: see my answer again plz

Comment: @Alex: Example: $a = $b = 10; both $a and $b will have value of 10. b is equal to 10 and a is equal to b which is actually 10 making a's value also 10. You can translate it in your own way :)

Comment: @Sarfraz While your first line is identical in functionality to @alex' question, the second line is not (unless `Arr::get` will return the same value for different inputs, which would make it non-sensical).

Comment: @deceze: you are right i think, i did not notice that, thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz Uhmm... What about leaving the second line alone? Please? :o) While technically brilliant, `list(...) = array(...)` is just so much more expensive and harder to read. If you insist on writing it on one line, just do `$a = ...; $b = ...;`. It's virtually impossible to make this any more concise without obfuscating it. :-)

Comment: @deceze: "What about leaving the second line alone?" yeah that is good way to go with, and i am not sure list way will provide much performance gain :)

Answer (score 1):

`$sortA == $sortB` so that part is just duplication. Calculate `$sortA` once wherever you set `$this->sortBy`. The `Arr::get` lines you're stuck with. The `return $a < $b;` seems wrong, you should be returning a -ve, 0, +ve number.

```
...
function setSortBy($sortBy) {
    $this->sortBy = $sortBy;
    $this->sortByCam = inflector::camelize(str_replace('-', '_', $sortBy));
}
....

public function sortProperties($a, $b) {

    $a = Arr::get($a, $this->sortByCam);
    $b = Arr::get($b, $this->sortByCam);

    if (is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)) {
        return $a - $b;
    } else {
        return strcasecmp($a, $b); 
    }

}
```

Something like that. The main idea to get the camelizing part out of the loop.

Comment: The return `return $a < $b;` does work how I intended it to. I guess positive number = true or negative number = false

Comment: `true` gets cast to `1`, `false` gets cast to `0` and your sort is lobotomised because the function can't indicate numeric `$a` is greater than `$b`. It also doesn't match the same sense as your strcasecmp which will return -1 if `$a < $b`. If it's working and you're happy with it then it doesn't matter, but it isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `strcasecmp` will return an int (1, 0, or -1) and `<` will return a boolean. You really need to be using one or the other. Also note that `strnatcasecmp` will probably give you the behavior you want for both numbers and strings so try this one:

```
public function sortProperties($a, $b) {
  $aInflected = Arr::get($a, $sort = inflector::camelize(str_replace('-', '_', $this->sortBy)));
  return strcasecmp($aInflected, Arr::get($b, $sort));
}
```